# Data transformation using Lodash in a more readable way

Tags: javascript, lodash.js

I don't like how transforming the data requires a bunch of nested functions. It's not very readable. Is there a more readable way to do the same transformations in Lodash?

```
var templates = {
  "fullRenderV80": {
    "stuff": "stuff",
    "screenshots": [
      {
        "device": "iPhone 6",
        "position": 1
      },
      {
        "device": "Watch",
        "position": 2
      }
    ]
  },
  "fullRenderV70": {
    "stuff": "stuff",
    "screenshots": [
      {
        "device": "iPhone 6",
        "position": 1
      },
      {
        "device": "iPad",
        "position": 2
      }
    ]
  }
}

var transformedData = _.groupBy(_.map(templates, 'screenshots'), function(screenshotsArray) {
  return _.reduce(screenshotsArray, function(templateDevicesName, screenshot) {
    return templateDevicesName.concat(screenshot.device)
  }, []).join(' + ')
})

// transformedData is this:
//{
//  "iPhone 6 + Watch": [
//    [
//      {
//        "device": "iPhone 6",
//        "position": 1
//      },
//      {
//        "device": "Watch",
//        "position": 2
//      }
//    ]
//  ],
//  "iPhone 6 + iPad": [
//    [
//      {
//        "device": "iPhone 6",
//        "position": 1
//      },
//      {
//        "device": "iPad",
//        "position": 2
//      }
//    ]
//  ]
//}
```

Answer (score 1):

Take advantage of lodash's `_()` wrapper function, which wraps a value, and allows chaining of methods.

```
function grouper(screenshotsArray){
  return _.reduce(screenshotsArray, function(templateDevicesName, screenshot) {
    return templateDevicesName + ' + ' + screenshot.device;
  }, '');
}

var transformedData = _(templates).map('screenshots').groupBy(grouper).value();
```